# How to write ms sql code for two column with same datas in MS SQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010, django-mssql

Here it two table.

```
Table1
SchoolID   Teacher_name   comm_yr
01          John            1990
02          Heley           1995
03         George          1994
04          Chris           1998
05          Mary            1993

Table2
School_ID   Student_name
01        Heley
02        Chris
03        Chris
04        Mary
05        Heley
```

I would like to list the year each student has done as student and the year each student has done as teacher.

```
    SELECT Teacher_name, comm_yr As Teacher_comm_yr, comm_yr As Student_comm_yr
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
WHERE comm_yr (SELECT comm_yr As Teacher_comm_yr From Table1
Where teacher_name=student_name);
```

The Table is showing

```
Teacher_name    Teacher_comm_yr  Student_comm_yr
John                   1990 1990
Heley                 1995  1995
George                 1994 1994
Chris                  1998 1998
Mary                    1993    1993
```

But What I want is

```
Teacher_name    Teacher_comm_yr Student_comm_yr
John               1990 
Heley               1995     1990
George              1994    
Chris               1998      1995
Chris               1998     1994
Mary                1993     1998
```

But I could only execute the same year
Can you please help..

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide desired output sample.

Comment: It's having error. I can't even execute it

Comment: what he means is for the above two base tables what is the output that you expect to see.. you dont have to run the query.. build it yourself by typing it out.. :/

Comment: I have already edited it. Please ignore the sequence of year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes.

```
SELECT 
  t1.Teacher_name, 
  t2.Student_name, 
  t1.comm_yr AS Teacher_comm_yr, 
  t1.comm_yr AS Student_comm_yr
FROM Table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t2.student_name = t1.teacher_name;
```

I do not understand where Chris got 1995 from, based on your data.

So how about:

```
SELECT t.SchoolID,
       t.Teacher_name,
       t.comm_yr,
       q.SchoolID,
       q.Teacher_name,
       q.Student_name,
       q.comm_yr
FROM   table11 t
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.SchoolID,
                         a.Teacher_name,
                         b.Student_name,
                         a.comm_yr
                  FROM   table11 AS a
                         INNER JOIN table22 AS b
                           ON a.SchoolID = b.School_ID) AS q
         ON t.Teacher_name = q.Student_name;
```

I have included more fields (columns) than necessary, to test the idea.

Comment: Chris was the student under Heley from t1

Comment: Thanks for the help
But It is showing like the first table. All the years are same. I want the table like 2nd one.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help
I can execute now